# Не получается решить задачу.С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str,abl;
    cin >> str;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
        if(str[i]!='a'||str[i]!='o'||str[i]!='y'||str[i]!='e'||str[i]!='u'||str[i]!='i')
        {
            cout << "." << str[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Задача в том,чтобы убрать гласные буквы,то есть a,o,y,e,u,i и например если ввести IITU,то output должен быть .t,если test то .t.s.t,и ввести их с точками

Comment: Вы `||` с `&&` не перепутали?

Comment: Упс,правильно оказывается,но можете объяснить,почему же там идет лог.оператор ИЛИ?

Comment: _Я_ должен объяснить _вам,_ почему в _вашем_ коде стоит «или» (`||`) вместо «и» (`&&`) :-) ?  На этот вопрос ответ знаете только вы.

Comment: Нет,просто думая логически,то там разве не должно быть "или"?
Я вас прошу объяснить почему же там должно быть "и" а не "или".

Comment: Потому что вам нужно выводить только когда «(буква НЕ РАВНА „а“) И (буква НЕ РАВНА „е“) И (буква НЕ РАВНА (…)»  Дальше сами :-)

Comment: Потому что если символ равен одной букве, то он автоматически на равен всем другим и поэтому результат всегда будет тру независимо от символа.

Comment: Обратите внимание, есть такая функция ([strchr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)), которая ищет вхождение символа в строке. Т.о. вы можете сделать строку из гласных (`const char *v = "aoyeui";`) и натравить на нее strchr() -- `if (!strchr(v, str[i])) ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не или, а как раз таки И, потому что у вас проверка на НЕравенство
буква не равна всем гласным

м или можно было сделать так

```
if(str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'o'||str[i] == 'y' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'i')
{
   // если любая из гласных - ничего не делаем
}
else
{
    std::cout << "." << str[i];
}
```

Comment: `==`, а не `=`.

Comment: Да, и то верно )

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
// #include <bits/stdc++.h> // Этот заголовок вам нужен?

using vector_chars = ::std::vector<char>;

const vector_chars map_chars =
{
    'A', 'a',
    'E', 'e',
    'I', 'i',
    'O', 'o',
    'U', 'u'
};

int main()
{
    ::std::string str, abl;
    ::std::cin >> str;
    for (::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        vector_chars::const_iterator it =
                ::std::find(map_chars.begin(), map_chars.end(), str[i]);

        ::std::cout << (it == map_chars.end() ? (::std::string{'.', str[i]}) : "");
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Input:

```
test
```

Output:

```
.t.s.t
```

Comment: полагаю необходимо не заменить гласные буквы на точки, а вывести согласные с точкой перед собой